# Multiple column output using a hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I am trying to create a Hash Table that contains 3 columns.

```
 SERVER_NAME  PROCESS_NAME  SERVER_STATUS   PROCESS_AVAILABLE
 SERVER1      app1.exe      RUNNING         YES
 SERVER1      app2.exe      RUNNING         NO
 SERVER2      app1.exe      OFFLINE         NO
 SERVER2      app2.exe      OFFLINE         NO
 SERVER3      app1.exe      RUNNING         YES
 SERVER3      app2.exe      RUNNING         YES
```

So far, I've tried this

```
$SERVERLIST = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\servers\serverManager.bin"
$PROCESSMONITOR  = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\process\application.bin"

$testList = @{Name=$SERVERLIST;Process=$PROCESSMONITOR}
```

The list of servers are in the "serverManager.bin" file. This is a CSV file that contains a list of the servers.

The list of processes that I am interested in monitoring are in the "application.bin" file. This is a CSV file that contains a list of the applications (as seen by PowerShell). [see code below]

```
 Get-Process -ComputerName $server -name $process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I want to build a report which tells an admin which server is running and which process is running from the list that we are interested in monitoring.

I can check if the process is running
I can check if a server is online

My question is what do I need to do to get output like what's posted above

Comment: *"I am trying to create a Hash Table that contains 3 columns."* - your example shows four columns....

Comment: The 3rd and 4th column don't exist when I import my data from the CSV file. Should I create them and leave it empty? Is that all I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the actual question here? You are creating a hash table with two keys (i.e. `Name` and `Process`) where the `Name` key has a value of `$SERVERLIST` and the `Process` key has a value of `$PROCESSMONITOR`. I assume that isn't what you want to be doing?

Comment: You need to create a hash table entry for *each* server not just one.

Comment: I am also not clear on what is being asked here. The title says you find hash tables confusing, but the content of the question is more or less asking for a solution to your report?

Comment: Looks like you just want to have a custom object for output.

Comment: @Matt - Thank you for the quick response. But if I use a custom object, would I be able to do the same things as a hash Table (sorting)? Or would I need to create my own Sort.

Comment: @softwareisfun It is no different then how you would work with data from something like `Import-CSV`

Comment: @EtanReisner The $SERVERLIST is just a list of server names (PC01, PC02, PC03, etc). $PROCESSMONITOR is usually 1 process but I wanted it to be able to have more than 1 process if needed.

Comment: Yes, I see what the data is. And I see what you did. You seem to have not understood that you have a *single* string in `$SERVERLIST` and you are sticking that into a *single* value in your hash table with your code. When what you want to be doing is creating a hash table where the *keys* are your server names and the values are arrays of processes. Either that or an array or hash tables with `Name` and `Process` keys where the value of `Name` is a single server same and the value of `Process` is an array of processes. In any case you need arrays.

Comment: If you are reporting on more than one process for a single server, you can't use the server name as a key (since there'd be duplicated), unless of course you create the status of all the processes for that server into one big string, that would be stored as the value for that key.

Comment: @campbell.rw If my server is the "Key". Can my processes be another hashtable within the 1st hashtable? (I'd always appreciate some code to help out with an idea)

Comment: @software is fun Yes that would certainly be possible. Could even just be a nested array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While hashtables play a part in this answer you are not looking for hashtables at all really. Looking at [about_hash_tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx)

> A hash table, also known as a dictionary or associative array, is a
>       compact data structure that stores one or more key/value **pairs**.

While you can nest whatever you want into the value you really are not looking for a hashtable. What I think you want is a custom PowerShell object that contains the results of each of your queries.

`Get-Process` does take arrays for both `-Computer` and `-Name` but they would omit results where either the computer does not exist or the process does not. Since you want that information you need to run a single cmdlet for each computer/process pair.

I use a hashtable only to create each individual "row" which is converted to a PowerShell object and collected as an array. I don't want to confuse but I know this working with at least 2.0 which is why I do it this way.

```psh
$SERVERLIST | ForEach-Object{
    $computer = $_
    $PROCESSMONITOR | ForEach-Object{
        $process = $_
        $props = @{
            Server_Name = $computer
            Process_Name = $process
        }

        # Check if the computer is alive. Better this was if $processes is large
        If(Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1){
            $props.Server_Status = "Running"
            $result = Get-Process -Name $process -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            If($result){
                $props.Process_Available = "Yes"
            } else {
                $props.Process_Available = "No"
            }
        } else {
            $props.Server_Status = "Offline"
            $props.Process_Available = "No"
        }

        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
    }
} | Select Server_Name,Process_Name,Server_Status,Process_Available
```

So now that we have a proper object you can now use other cmdlets like `Where-Object`, `Sort-Object` and etc.

Comment: @softwareisfun Right now they are just output to the console. Just pipe them into `Export-CSV` would be the most efficient option.